# How to stop Mysql ibd files from continuously growing

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have a mysql 5.5.44-0ubuntu0.14.04.1-log DB that has 2 tables that get a lot of data written to them then deleted within 48 hours, it is for a [Salt](http://saltstack.com) system.  The my.cnf is specifying `innodb_file_per_table` and the problem is that the .ibd files for the 2 tables keep growing and filling up the disk space.

I'm using this query to check the usage of the tables space and compare to the .ibd file on disk:

```
SELECT table_name AS "Table", round(((data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024 / 1024), 2) "Size in GB" FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE table_schema = "$DB_NAME" AND table_name = "$TABLE_NAME";
```

For the `jids` table that returns 30.51 GB but 57 GB is the file size, and for the `salt_returns` table it shows 24.40 GB but the file size is 79 GB.

On the surface it would seem like the table space is just not using all the innodb allocated space but the problem is that those files continue to grow when it would seem they shouldn't.  I've been using `pt-online-schema-change` to reclaim some of the disk space but doing so requires ample space that I'm now running out of.

Here is the composition of the tables:

```
mysql> describe jids;
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| jid   | varchar(255) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| load  | mediumtext   | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

mysql> show indexes in jids;
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| jids  |          0 | jid      |            1 | jid         | A         |      174836 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| jids  |          1 | idx_jid  |            1 | jid         | A         |        3067 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+

mysql> describe salt_returns;
+------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default           | Extra |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
| fun        | varchar(50)  | NO   | MUL | NULL              |       |
| jid        | varchar(255) | NO   | MUL | NULL              |       |
| return     | mediumtext   | NO   |     | NULL              |       |
| id         | varchar(255) | NO   | MUL | NULL              |       |
| success    | varchar(10)  | NO   |     | NULL              |       |
| full_ret   | mediumtext   | NO   |     | NULL              |       |
| alter_time | timestamp    | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |       |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+

mysql> show indexes in salt_returns;
+--------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table        | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+--------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| salt_returns |          1 | id       |            1 | id          | A         |           9 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| salt_returns |          1 | jid      |            1 | jid         | A         |      221863 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| salt_returns |          1 | fun      |            1 | fun         | A         |           9 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+--------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

**Show `create table` and `table status` info:**

```
+-------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                            |
+-------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| jids  | CREATE TABLE `jids` (
  `jid` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `load` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `jid` (`jid`),
  KEY `idx_jid` (`jid`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
+-------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

+--------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table        | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               |
+--------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| salt_returns | CREATE TABLE `salt_returns` (
  `fun` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `jid` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `return` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `success` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `full_ret` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `alter_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  KEY `id` (`id`),
  KEY `jid` (`jid`),
  KEY `fun` (`fun`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
+--------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

+------------------------+--------+---------+------------+--------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-------------+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------------+-----------------+----------+----------------+---------+
| Name                   | Engine | Version | Row_format | Rows   | Avg_row_length | Data_length | Max_data_length | Index_length | Data_free   | Auto_increment | Create_time         | Update_time | Check_time | Collation       | Checksum | Create_options | Comment |
+------------------------+--------+---------+------------+--------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-------------+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------------+-----------------+----------+----------------+---------+
| jids                   | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    | 352170 |          67763 | 23864442880 |               0 |      7864320 | 35754344448 |           NULL | 2015-10-15 15:45:52 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8_general_ci |     NULL |                |         |
| salt_returns           | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    | 127156 |          74548 |  9479258112 |               0 |     12632064 | 73631006720 |           NULL | 2015-10-12 09:12:50 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8_general_ci |     NULL |                |         |
+------------------------+--------+---------+------------+--------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-------------+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------------+-----------------+----------+----------------+---------+
```

Comment: Possibly fragmented indexes?

Comment: Not sure but this  could possibly be use-case of partitioning. Create partition and drop  them instead of deleting!!

Comment: Whats the mysql version? Are there any long running transactions? (not probable as the `pt-online-schema-change` should not be able to finish in such case).

Comment: Maybe mysql 5.5.43 displays it differently than mariadb, but it looks like `describe jids` doesn't match `show indexes in jids`; none of the shown indexes are `PRIMARY`.  Either way, it looks like The index `jids.idx_jid` is redundant since `jids.jid` (probably the primary key) is the same.

Comment: Please use `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; it is more descriptive than `describe`.  Also please provide `SHOW TABLE STATUS`.

Comment: @jkavalik there are no long running transactions

Comment: @jkavalik no long running transactions. Version is 5.5.3

Comment: @bwizzy 5.5.3 was not even a *stable* release and is more than 5 years old. You should update that as fast as possible (newest atm is 5.5.46 )

Comment: @jkavalik sorry, typo: 5.5.44-0ubuntu0.14.04.1-log

Comment: @RickJames basic problem is that the table doesn't consistently hold that many rows, data is added, then deleted < 36 hours later.  But it seems the action of inserting and deleting is leaving behind artifacts that are filling the disk.

Answer (score 1):

Does "Salt" continue to insert rows?  And never delete them?  If so, the .ibd files will continue to grow.

For purging "old" data, `PARTITIONing` is an excellent tool.  Here are details for such:
http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint
Keep in mind that converting to a partitioned table via `ALTER TABLE` will lock the table for a long time and need enough disk space for an extra copy.  If this is not viable; we can discuss alternatives.

Side notes (probably Salt's fault):

- `varchar(255)` makes an awful `PRIMARY KEY`.
- I assume the `mediumtext` columns are bulky?  If so, it would be more efficient to compress them in the client and store them in `mediumblob`.  For normal text, this would shrink the disk footprint by 3x.

Comment: Yes, I've heard of the partition table, but these tables can't be locked for much time at all without taking the application offline.  Hence why i used pt-online-schema-change for optimizing.

Comment: `OPTIMIZE TABLE` is usually a waste of time.

Comment: If you `PARTITION` by, say, "hour" and can drop the partition with data that is 49 hours old, then it solves all the problems mentioned.  Locking is very brief; the ibd won't bloat (since you are inserting into new partition and dropping old partition); etc.